# Win10 uninstall driver but keep ability to reinstall

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I want to uninstall some audio drivers, but would like to be able to reinstall them later just in case. How can I uninstall a driver while retaining some information about it that will enable me to reinstall it later, particularly regarding drivers whose names return no relevant results after extensive googling? Where can I find some information about the driver that would allow me to find it again online or somewhere in my file system?

Comment: Download drivers from the computer manufacturer's Support Site and keep them in a folder - I do this routinely.

Comment: Thanks. Would that be the System Manufacturer or Baseboard Manufacturer, if there's a difference?

Comment: I would use the Manufacturer's drivers to be sure.

Comment: Sorry, what I'm asking is: the manufacurer of what? When I go to System Information, there is a variety of manufacturers depending on the component. I'm newish to this.

Comment: I use brand name computers and use that manufacturer. The model number of the computer should tell you which driver. That is how it works for me.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download drivers from the computer manufacturer's Support Site and keep them in a folder - I do this routinely.

I use brand name computers and use that manufacturer. The model number of the computer should tell you which driver. That is how it works for me.